# querying Elasticsearch for parse date field with format

Tags: python, datetime, elasticsearch

I am querying Elasticsearch based on date, passing in a date and time string in this format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, but Elasticsearch and DateTime are unable to accept this format.

I am writing a script that takes input and queries Elasticsearch based on those inputs, primarily by index and date-time. I've written the script using command line arguments, entering the date-time in the same format, and the script runs perfectly. However, when I try converting the script running with hardcoded inputs, the error appears:

> error elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to parse date field
>   [2019-07-01 00:00:00] with format
>   [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]')

```
#this throws the error
runQueryWithoutCommandLine("log4j-*", "2019-07-01 00:00:00", "csv", "json")

#this does not throw error
def runQueryWithCommandLine(*args):
  # "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" date-time format is given in commandline
```

Why is this error appearing, and how can I get rid of it? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The [Date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis" in elastic uses the [ISO date format standards](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateOptionalTimeParser--).

As can be seen in link above, the ISO format for string representation of date is :

```
date-opt-time     = date-element ['T' [time-element] [offset]]
```

In your case, the time portion is separated by a whitespace and not the 'T' and hence the parsing error.

In addition, as I see the time mentioned is 00:00:00, you can simply omit this as this is what that's taken as default is no time portion is specified.

So, any of below date value will work:

```
1) 2019-07-01T00:00:00
2) 2019-07-01
```

Comment: Hi Shailesh, thanks for the help! My goal is to parse the date value so that there is no need for the "T". From my perspective, inputing a date-time value as "2019-07-01 00:00:00" is more natural than "2019-07-01T00:00:00". I've written some code that runs perfect with "2019-07-01 00:00:00" from the cmd line, but I can't figure out how to run it in that date-time format without the cmd line. Thanks again!

Comment: ISO Format did not work for me. It still threw the same error.